# Performance issue, flat file vs database storage

Tags: sql-server, json, performance, database-performance

I am working on a project that asked me to develop a system to provide JSON output, the following is the flow:

1a) Some tables will be updated via the administration panel (my company side)

1b) Some related tables will be updated via the administration panel (partner side)

> -- Let say **SuperHeroes** & **Males** were updated in 1a), **Studios** & **Years** were updated in 1b)

2) Client browse our site and request an information set which:

- Has an enabled and not deleted row in **SuperHeroes** (Ant-man)
- Has an enabled and not deleted row in **Males** linked to **SuperHeroes** (Scott Lang)
- Joined the above records then look if they are linked to and exists in **Studios** (Marvel)
- Linked to an existing row in **Years** (2015)

3) A very small data will be outputted to a JSON string as the following: { id:1,type:marvel },{ id:1,type:dc }

> *All rows in the above 4 tables will be updated/deleted at anytime without notification, [No Foreign Key as well]*

---

I am thinking to update the information in a flat file every time **1a** is performed (since we can update the system of my company side but not the partner side, and they are *rejected* to save some extra information into a flat file, **so the situation is we have no easy way to know if the *Studios* or *Years* tables are modified**)

Then while the JSON request will first load the information from the flat file (all outputting data will be stored in this file), then use a simple SQL statement to filter if a linked record exists in **Studios** & **Years**

---

I have done my research and getting confused, I concluded when the data amount is small then flat file will be great but beware the file comes larger and larger (**The flat file we are talking will noway more than 50 rows at 1 time, and that should not be modified frequently**)

Some answer said database is good at Query data (**I think so and the requirement will perform SQL check too**)

So I don't know if its good when my data amounts are small but still need some communication with the database..

I appreciate your time and your help, all idea & hints are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion regarding amount of data is absolutely correct, and file should handle those 50 rows, but.. 
Using database as storage should give you more options in the future, e.g.:

- you'll be able to produce any output due to separation of data
  representation (today it's JSON, but what if you have to produce XML
  at some point? will you add files that store XML's next to JSON
  files? and then CSV or any other?)
- transactions will guarantee the ACID
- scalability and performance - if your dataset get bigger (you never know :)), many
  DB's offer you many possibilities like table partitioning, partitioning-based clustering
  or replication

Wrong choices regarding architecture and technology made at the beginning of the project will always backfire.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply, the reason that makes me consider file system is those data is in JSON format that will be returned via ajax call.
Let say the file is just going to store the details info of an enabled product (sorry I misunderstood the requirement while I post the quest), and that should be 50 product max at the same time.

While the client go visit example.com/Product.php?pid=1
I would like to just call $.ajax("./Details/1.txt") and I think this should reduce the load of Database

Comment: Well, I also like to make everything as simple and effortless as possible, but again, it always backfire at some point, e.g.: I need to change the model, even just a field name.. and I have 50 files to edit instead of one mapping in ORM type definition. DB load shouldn't be a concern - any DB should be able to serve thousands of (simple) results per second.
If I were you, I'd try to answer to following questions: 50 products enabled? so how many will be disabled after 1 year? can you enable/disable them any time? will you be able to do it easily (in one call ) or one by one? and so on..

Comment: The idea is every time something is changed in the database, the corresponding file will be updated, if the record is deleted, the file will be deleted as well. The only purpose of those files are just serve the ajax request.. They exist to reduce database workload (I don't know how much but 'better than nothing - My client')